# three.js How to programatically produce a plane from dataset

Tags: three.js, 3d

I'm working on the 3D representation of technical equipments in buildings with three.js. First, user clicks on a leaflet map to determine the edges of the building's roof. Once its done I got the image of the area map, the image of the roof (with canvas) and an array of the left/top position of each user's click. I'm now able to create the building at its right place and orientation on the map. (I also have the image of the building plan loaded by user).

With the user's clicks array, I can create the walls (white + opacity 0.5) depending the number of building's stairs :

[image: Text]

The next step is to put on each stair a lot of objects connected together to a technical duct (yellow vertical wire) with green cables. The position, type, color of each object (red=electrical intrance, green=wifi) are defined by a set on JSON data.

Now the problem: these objects+cables are here on this screenshot automatically positioned depending the initial map size. The last step to achieve is now to position them on their right place depending the building size and its orientation/rotation in scene.

I've manually created the artificial yellow plane on the ground, which is exactly the area including the whole building. It remains now to add the 'objects group' to this plane to get their exact real position in the building. The question is: is it possible and how to programmatically produce this yellow plane from the walls position, size and angle?

It wouldn't be hard to achieve with a rectangular building with 4 right-angled corners, but here with 6 walls and different angles it's beyond my abilities.

```
      // data sended to three:

      batims=[["Bulding's name",3,1130,510,[ 452,298,649,150,704,182,664,255,642,246,494,355 ] ]
                             // 3 = nb of stairs, 1130+510 = map size, [ 452,298,.. = clicks ]

      
      // walls production

      var mapsize = [batims[i][2],batims[i][3]; // 1130,510
      var hstair = 40;  // height of each stair

      for(c=0;c<batims[i][4].length;c+=2){  
                
            posleft = batims[i][4][c];
            postop = batims[i][4][c+1];
            
            fromleft = Math.floor(mapsize[0]/2);
            fromtop = Math.floor(mapsize[1]/2); 

            startleft = posleft-fromleft;
            startop = postop-fromtop;

            if(batims[i][4][c+2]){   
                thisleft = batims[i][4][c+2];
                thistop = batims[i][4][c+3];
                endleft = thisleft-fromleft;
                endtop = thistop-fromtop;
            }
            else{  // no more wall to create: ended the last one on first wall position
                thisleft = batims[i][4][0];
                thistop = batims[i][4][1];
                endleft = thisleft-fromleft;
                endtop = thistop-fromtop;
            }

            deltaX = endleft-startleft;
            deltaY = endtop-startop;
            degs = Math.atan2(deltaY,deltaX)
            deltaX *= deltaX;
            deltaY *= deltaY;
            size = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(deltaX + deltaY));

            var wallGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(size,(hstair*batims[i][1]));
            val = 0xFFFFFF;
            opa = 0.5;
            if(deltaX > deltaY){val = 0x000000; opa = 0.05;} // shaded wall
            var wallMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:val,transparent:true, opacity:opa, side:THREE.DoubleSide});
            var walls = new THREE.Mesh(wallGeometry, wallMaterial);
            walls.position.set((startleft+endleft)/2,(hstair*batims[i][1])/2,(startop+endtop)/2);
            walls.rotation.y = -degs;
            scene.add(walls);
        }
```

Thanks for help or suggestions

Comment: Found the solution:
We always are able to get the length+angle of each wall: 2 arrays `sizes[]` and `angles[]`.
Let start with the first wall, the one starting from left and going up. Its length is 246 (var size[0]) and its angle = `Math.asin((endtop-startop)/size[0])`. 
The second wall have its length (size[1]=63) and its angle `angles[1]=0.52`. 
We now can get the virtual length of the small side of the yellow triangle shown under the AP3 object : `Math.cos(angles[1]-angles[0])*dists[1]`= 25.
The yellow plane has the computed length 246+25=271, which is exactly the size I've given.

Comment: Its a little more complicated for its width because we have 2 triangles to compute but it works the same way: `Math.sin(angles[1]-angles[0])*dists[1]` gives 58 (opposite side) and `Math.cos(angles[2])*dists[2]` (adjacent) gives 40. We now are able to create the yellow plane 271x98, rotate + place it, then add the 'objects group' inside.